# Does the MATLAB ksdensity function perform the boundary correction?

Tags: matlab, statistics, kernel-density

One who is familiar with kernel density estimation should know that there exist some methods for boundary correction. The ksdensity function has the capacity for the [L U] bounded support. Then, my question is, "what boundary correction method is used here?" Reflection or renormalization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how renormalization is done traditionally in KDE estimation, but by judging from this piece of the code in `ksdensity` that deals with support (Run `type ksdensity` or `edit ksdensity` in your MATLAB command window)

```
function ty = apply_support(yData,L,U)
% Compute transformed values of data
if L==-Inf && U==Inf    % unbounded support
    ty = yData;
elseif L==0 && U==Inf   % positive support
    ty = log(yData);
else                    % finite support [L, U]
    ty = log(yData-L) - log(U-yData);    % same as log((y-L)./(U-y))
end
```

I would expect the bound support output `ty = log(yData-L) - log(U-yData)` to be a normalized and log-scaled version of the original signal `yData`.

Comment: No problem. I think this is a piece of information that should be made more explicit by MATLAB, and the documentation has nothing.